# Not Able to access values with .Type swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

Why am I not able to assign and read value from Type B in below code? `B.self` should be passed as a type and not an instance, so it should access static var in `class B` right?

```
class A{

}

class B:A{
   static var a = 5
}

class c{
     static func a(){
        b(type: B.self)

    }
    static func b(type:B.Type){
        print(type.a)
    }

    func takeObject<T>(type:T.Type){


        print(type(of:String.self)) // String.Type
        print(type) // B
        print(type.a) // Value of type 'T' has no member 'a'
        var a :type // Use of undeclared type 'type'

    }

}
let objects : c = c()
objects.takeObject(object: B.self)
```

Correct me please, I am new on this topic and it seems quite interesting.

Comment: It is very hard to tell what you’re asking. Firstly, what is `a` doing in the `takeObjects()` function? And what type are you trying to assign it? Why are you printing the value of `String.Type`? Why are you doing this at all? The only thing I can help you with is line 3 of the `takeObjects()` function. Do `print((type as! B).a)`. This casts the generic type to the specific type `B`. Also, rename the function parameter `type` to something else to avoid conflicts with the function `type(of:)`. Sorry, but this is all I can do with the way that the question is currently worded.

Comment: @AlexH sorry for code wording, I want to pass custom types as function parameters, and then use them.

Comment: What do you want to use them for? @Tushar Sharma

Comment: Will you be making a limited number of objects that you can keep track of?

Comment: @AlexH yes 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0):

As i think you just want to add objects of type `B` so you can specify generic `T` of type `B` as below,

```
class A {}

class B: A {
    static var a = 5
}

class c {
    static func a() {
        b(type: B.self)

    }
    static func b(type: B.Type){
        print(type.a)
    }

    func takeObject<T: B>(type: T.Type){
        print(type)
        print(type.a)
        var a : T
    }
}

let objects : c = c()
objects.takeObject(type: B.self)
```

Comment: What if don't want to be specific with B?

Comment: As you are accessing `a` as `type.a` inside `takeObject` so all those objects should be child of class `B` because `a` is declared inside that class.